# How do I center these items properly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the code here but basically the problem is I have these product cards and I am trying to get them in the center but also align them with the other cards if that makes sense.

https://codepen.io/manfreebie/pen/NWNvyGz

Here is a visual of what I want to accomplish vs. what is actually happening. It looks fine at first till you try to resize it.

I have tried to make the cocktail-container have the value flex-start instead of center for the justify-content attribute like this

```
#cocktails-container {
  max-width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

but that leaves a lot of whitespace on the right side when I resize it. I have tried playing around a little bit with inline-block and using text-align instead but that didn't work either.

[image: Here is a visual of what I want to accomplish vs. what is actually happening]

Comment: Did you try inline-block and float: left?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code.

```
#cocktails-container::after {
  content: "";
  flex: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am only sharing parts that I changed, the rest is the same.

```
#cocktails-container {
  width: 70%; // You can adjust this for your needs
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: start;
}

// Removed margin from .cocktail but added padding to the a tag
.cocktail {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  width: 33%; // You should adjust this for different screen widths, mobile 100% large 25% etc.
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box; // This is necessary to include padding in '33% width'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,To How do I center these items properly?

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 200px;
}
    .box .selected {
    align-self: center;
}

<div class="box">
  <div class="selected">Three</div>
</div>
```

I hope this code will be useful for you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I identified while checking the code is that you are using a `margin`  `margin: 50px 0px;` for the `.cocktail` class. Change it to the below one.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .cocktail {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }
}
```

Giving margin value `50px 0px;` will make the left and right margin to zero in the samller resolution. Update that to `50px auto` that will give left and right margins auto value.